# Alternative to stopwatch?

Tags: c#, wpf, stopwatch

I am working on a very simple stopwatch using WPF but using the `System.Diagnostics` stopwatch was very slow and not reliable at all, compared to my system clock every 1 second from my application was 3 seconds on an actual clock.

I did some search about stopwatch being slow, found lots of results but no solution to it, so I decided to come up with my own counter.

Here is an sample of what I came up with:

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer _update;
DateTime _started;
bool isRunning = false;
```

The update thread:

```
_update = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
{
    if (isRunning)
        iTimer.Content = new DateTime((DateTime.Now - _started).Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}, this.Dispatcher);
```

I have 2 buttons, bToggle which is resposible for starting, stopping and resuming it and another button called bReset.

```
private void bReset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isRunning = false;
    iTimer.Content = "00:00:00";
    bToggle.Content = "Start";
}

private void bToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)bToggle.Content == "Start")
    {
        isRunning = true;
        _started = DateTime.Now;
        bToggle.Content = "Stop";
    }
    else if ((string)bToggle.Content == "Resume")
    {
        isRunning = true;
        bToggle.Content = "Stop";
    }
    else
    {
        isRunning = false;
        bToggle.Content = "Resume";
    }
}
```

It works fine to start and reset but since I am using the actual time if I stop and resume, it will jump the seconds until the actual time.

How could I solve this problem or is there an alternative to stopwatch that actually have a good accuracy on the current time ?

Comment: What were you using `StopWatch` for?

Comment: For a stopwatcher ? To put it simple it counts from 0 until u stop or reset.

Comment: It just sounds like you were trying to use it as a timer.

Comment: Something like this http://www.sport-impianti.com/wp-content/gallery/atletica/4103.jpg but as a desktop application. Either way if u look at the above code, its a fully working on, I just need to figure out how to do the stop/resume function or if there is a better way to control it.

Comment: `StopWatch` has issues on some hardware(for example constant offsets between cores), but I never heard of a multiplicative error. Can you post your `StopWatch` code?

Comment: Now you are being silly. The `StopWatch` class is intended to count time differences. Timers are intended to execute pieces of code on a schedule. It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: CodeInChaos I would but I already got ride of it and moved to the above one after several tries and no useful results from searchs.

Comment: Oded LOL man, I am doing a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopwatch this my sound confusing as I was trying to use the StopWatch class to make a StopWatch, but thats what I am doing a Stopwatch for desktop that can be stopped and resumed.

Comment: Again, it sounds like you need a timer. Timers can be stopped and resumed.

Comment: I wrote a stopwatch/clock/countdown timer recently in WPF to be used at the back of a church to help the speaker know how long they've been preaching. You're welcome to the code if you want it.

Comment: @Oded that's why I was looking for an Alternative or solution to my current code but the Timers class hangs my UI.

Comment: @Guapo - There are _several_ different timer classes. You need to use the right one and your UI will not hang.

Comment: @Guapo: To choose the right timer, you could maybe take a look into [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to intruduce an additional variable `TimeSpan accumulatedTime` in which you save the elapsed interval whenever someone clicks stop.

And:

```
iTimer.Content = (new DateTime((DateTime.Now - _started).Ticks) + accumulatedTime).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: very appreciated, I have resolved it with the follow: `new DateTime((DateTime.Now.Subtract(accumulatedTime) - _tempo).Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss");`

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Timers.Timer`

You can start and stop this, and set a counter in the timers tick event.

This is a simple example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private int _time;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _time = 0;

        _timer = new Timer(1000);
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
    }

    void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                                         {
                                             _time++;
                                             tbTime.Text = _time.ToString();
                                         }));

    }

    private void btnStartStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_timer.Enabled)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="btnStartStop" Content="start/stop timer" Click="btnStartStop_Click" />
        <TextBlock Name="tbTime" Text="00:00" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: the fact I am using a thread is so it doesn't hang my application UI

Comment: this dosn't lock your UI, but if you want to be safe put the timer in a backgroundworker and forward the tick event to worker progresschanged event

Comment: jrb if you are constantly moving the app window it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is your problem:

```
_update = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal
```

It tells WPF that you want your delegate to execute 1000 times per second, and to schedule it at the second-highest priority. That's a higher priority than `Render` and `DataBind`, and I think both Render and DataBind are needed to actually display the updated value you put in `iTimer.Content`.

You should set the DispatcherPriority to Background and use a lower frequency (e.g. 20 ms - humans can't see anything faster than 50 fps, anyway.)

Comment: With the code in my question it updates just fine but using the stopwatch class it was not so that would cut out that line as being the problem in my opinion.